# Why are software-based attacks on TPMs so rare? How do TPMs protect against them?

Tags: linux, windows, security, secret-key, tpm

I'm working on obtaining a unique hardware fingerprint on a host through WMI.
However, I found that this approach was so vulnerable.

There are at least two attack vectors:

- attack on kernel space by memory manipulation
  https://github.com/Alex3434/wmi-static-spoofer
- attack on user space by dll-hooking
  https://dzone.com/articles/windows-api-hooking-and-dll-injection

Eventually, I survey the TPM technique as a hardware identification solution.
To me astonishment, software-based attack on TPM is so rare.

My question is

- by what why the TPM protect against the software-based attack such as dll-hooking and memory manipulation ?

Answer (score 0):

There are features in the TPM (at least in 2.0) that help to prevent such attacks.

- You can use attestation to check if a key is protected by the tpm.
- You can use the session based encryption/decryption to protect at least some data between your application and the TPM.

But if an attacker can perform any of the attacks you listed he must have managed to get admin or root rights on the system and therefore can perform other attacks to steal your data.